# pyspark executors' tasks are limited to 6 when writing out to avro

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

This is what my simple pyspark app does:

- join 200 row, with 20 million rows
- calculate cosine distance between 2 fields
- filter out those with cosine similarity below 0.9
- save the results of the filter (above 0.9) in avro format, using

  ```
   filtered_df.write.format('com.databricks.spark.avro').save('hdfs://path/result')
  ```

I'm using spark's dataframe to accomplish this(SQLContext). My cluster info is as follow:

- 13TB RAM (50% utilization)
- 2K+ vcores (60% utilization)

I run my spark job with the following:

```
spark-submit --num-executors 15 --executor-cores 5 --executor-memory 13G test.py
```

looking at my spark's UI, I saw some jobs consisting of 200 tasks. However, the save to avro step, consists of only 6 tasks running in parallel. The last time this ran, it takes about 1 day to complete. How can I optimize this? Any help would be appreciated. I'm new to spark. I was thinking to convert it to RDD map reduce, but read that Dataframe operation is actually more efficient.

Comment: Try to repartition the data before saving, see if that works !

Comment: I'm not working with RDD though. I'm working with DataFrame.

Comment: Dataframe can also be repartitioned at last underlying main collection is RDD only.

Comment: I tried using coalesce:     filtered_df.coalesce(100).write.format('com.databricks.spark.avro').save('hdfs://path/result'), but it's still ended up with 6 tasks.

Comment: Please attach your DAG Visualisation and the Tasks UI ,maybe we can get some help from there !